# OTP for email verification in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm making a bot that takes information from the user and books an appointment for him. When the user enters his email, I want the bot to send an OTP to verify his email. So far I have not been able to find any relevant content.

I have a single welcome intent, which then has a followup intent which takes all this information (Name, Email, Date, Time) and sets up the appointment. I want to add a step here to verify the email the user entered via OTP.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you've done so far and what, exactly, you're having problems with. As written, while we might understand what we're trying to do, the question is very broad and missing a lot of details that will help us help you. See  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just want to verify if the user entered email is valid or not. Bot will take the user's email and an otp will be sent to user's email from where the user can verify.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a [fulfillment webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) using the language and libraries of your choice that takes the email address, verifies it is a valid one, and then sends the OTP to the user.

Comment: That's the question. How will I setup a fulfillment webhook to do the specific task?

I'm able to receive the email in an entity and I'm also able to grab that email in the fulfillment. What's next?

Comment: This is why we ask for code that illustrates what you've done so far and what you're having problems with. "What's next" depends on what you've already done, but it sounds like "what's next" would be as I said - verify the address is valid and send the OTP to the user. *How* you do that depends on a lot of things.

Comment: Brother, I just want to know that how can I setup an OTP system to check the validity of Email entered by the user.

Comment: 1. Get Email
2. generate random code and send that with users email also save that with user data so you can verify it,